# iOS timeout functionality not working properly

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, timeout

I added this code which functions as an auto timeout in my app.  The `userDefaults doubleForKey:@"timeoutLength"` should be in minutes.  For example, if value is 500, that should mean 500 minutes.

I keep seeming to be hitting the timout loop though even when it hasn't really been 500 + min.  Is anything wrong in my code?  Perhaps a minutes/seconds error etc.

```
    [userDefaults setDouble:[[userContextDictionary valueForKey:@"autologout_idle_timeout"] doubleValue] forKey:@"timeoutLength"];


    double timeDifference = ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - [userDefaults doubleForKey:@"Close Time"]) / 60;

    if (timeDifference > [userDefaults doubleForKey:@"timeoutLength"]) {
        NSLog(@"Timeout Hit");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No Timeout");
    }
```

Edit:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [userDefaults setObject:[NSDate date]  forKey:@"Close Time"];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {   
    [userDefaults setDouble:[[userContextDictionary valueForKey:@"autologout_idle_timeout"] doubleValue] forKey:@"timeoutLength"];  
    //This is an int like 500, or 600, etc. 

    NSDate *closeDate = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"Close Time"]
    NSTimeInterval timeWhenClosedTimeInterval = [closeDate timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSTimeInterval todayTimeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

    NSTimeInterval timeDifference = ((todayTimeInterval - timeWhenClosedTimeInterval ) / 60);
    if (timeDifference > [userDefaults doubleForKey:@"timeoutLength"]) {
        NSLog(@"Timeout Hit");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No Timeout");
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSTimeInterval is expressed in *seconds*, not minutes.

[Here's the Apple doc where it's described](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html).

I'm not 100% certain what your ultimate problem with, but 500 seconds doesn't seem like nearly enough time.

In the meantime, I wrote up some changes to your code to demo for myself:

```
NSDate * yesterday = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: (-1 * 60 * 60 * 24 )];
NSTimeInterval yesterdayTimeInterval = [yesterday timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval todayTimeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

// this properly converts timeDifference in seconds to minutes
NSTimeInterval timeDifference = ((todayTimeInterval - yesterdayTimeInterval ) / 60);
NSLog( @"time difference is %4.2f", timeDifference );
```

which came up with 1400 minutes (divided by 60 minutes per hour = 24 hours).

Comment: Well the goal is to check if difference between timeClose and now is greater than timeoutLength. So am I off by a factor of min vs seconds?

Comment: yep, looks like it to me.  I've also edited my answer to demo for you.

Comment: I just added newly updated code based on your answer if you can check it out.  When the app is closed, I save the timestamp in NSUserDefauts.  Then when the app is launched the next time, i check if the time difference is greater than the `autologout_idle_timeout` userdefaults value.

Comment: I think there is an issue with `autologout_idle_timeout` being a `double` instead of a NSDate, but the number is always given to me like that, for example it could be 100, 500, or 1000, etc.

Comment: One thing I see right away is that you set your `Close Time` default as a NSDate and then you read it in as a `double`. You should be reading it in via `objectForKey`.

Comment: Ok, I fixed that. What about the fact that `timeout length` is a double yet `timeDifference` is a `NSTimeInterval`? Will this cause a problem or will it be ok?

Comment: `NSTimeInterval` is just another name for a `double` type, so you should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is there is some error with setting the NSUserDefaults values, or an error with your timeDifference calculation. Add this line and make sure you are actually setting the timeout length to 500:

```
NSLog(@"Timeout length: %f, close time: %f, time difference: %f", [userDefaults doubleForKey:@"timeoutLength"], [userDefaults doubleForKey:@"Close Time"], timeDifference);
```